# JavaScript implementation of modern UNIX crypt(3)?

Tags: javascript, linux, unix, encryption, crypt

Is there a pure JavaScript library to encrypt passwords like the UNIX [crypt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt), supporting modern encryption methods like SHA-256 or SHA-512? (e.g., `crypt('password', '$6$salt')` like in [the `crypt` module of Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html))  In addition, I would also need this to run in the browser without access to the underlying libc crypt() implementation.

### Background

I need to open Linux server accounts to people I can only communicate with via email.  I normally ask Linux and MacOSX users to encyrpt a password on the terminal command line and send the encrypted one to me; I do not currently have a solution for Windows users.

Thus I would like to write a small HTML page with a text box + JS code that encrypts the text entered as a SHA-512 password.  Then users could simply copy+paste the encrypted password in an email and that's it. No cleartext password would ever leave their computer.

### Prior art

I see this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427488/anybody-seen-a-crypt3-implementation-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401920/how-to-do-unix-crypt3-in-javascript), but:

- The first link does not really provide an answer, but advice that implementing JS encryption for client/server communication is not a good idea. This is not my use case.
- The solutions in the second link are not useful, as they either require access to the underlying libC `crypt()` implementation (via FFI), or they only provide the traditional DES encryption.

Comment: Looks like might be useful ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996030/php-function-crypt-in-javascript

Comment: Good question. You might end up being the one to write this.

Comment: I'd take a look at [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) and [Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) (the latter being promoted by CryptoJS author as a possible alternative).